# How to properly use the security function to get 15 min close on a 1 min chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using the security function to get 15 min close on a 1 min chart.  The data coming out is not as expected.

I am using security with barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_off, and the expectation is that I will get "na" values unless the 15 min bar closes.

```
current15Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close, barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_off)
previous15Min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close[1], barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_off)
```

I plotted the values and this is what I got in alert:

"current15Min ": 13811, ( incorrect, should be : 13830 )
"previous15Min": 13818.75, ( correct )

What am I missing?